# Bind variable to attribute of <paper-item-body>

Tags: data-binding, polymer

Is it possible to bind a variable to these `<paper-item-body>` attributes: `two-line` and `three-line`?

For example:

```
<paper-item>
  <paper-item-body {{item.lineCount}}>
    <div>Title</div>
    <div secondary>Description</div>
  </paper-item-body>
  <iron-icon></iron-icon>
</paper-item>
```

where `item.lineCount` is `'two-line'` or `'three-line'`.

I have used data bindings on a target attribute in other areas (i.e., `style$="color: {{myColor}};"`), but that method doesn't seem to work for `<paper-item-body>`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Attribute bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#attribute-binding) (i.e., with `$=`) are bound to Boolean variables, where the attribute is set when the bound value is `true`, and removed when `false`.

Assuming `item.enableTwoLines` is a Boolean, you'd bind `<paper-item-body>.twoLine` like this:

```
<paper-item-body two-line$="[[item.enableTwoLines]]">
  ...
</paper-item-body>
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo'
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-item/paper-item-body.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-checkbox/paper-checkbox.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <style>
        paper-checkbox {
          margin: 20px;
        }
        paper-item-body {
          border: solid 1px red;
          --paper-item-body-two-line-min-height: 200px;
        }
      </style>
      <paper-checkbox active="{{enableTwoLine}}">Enable 2-line paper-item</paper-checkbox>
      <paper-item>
        <paper-item-body two-line$="[[enableTwoLine]]">
          <div>Profile Photo</div>
          <div secondary>Change your Google+ profile photo</div>
        </paper-item-body>
      </paper-item>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/woJGWZ?editors=1010)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I have an array so I just have two-line$="{{item.enableTwoLine}}" three-line$="{{item.enableThreeLine}}" and then enableTwoLine: true.